# Unable to add Sonar Lint and SonarCube Plugin in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, sonarqube, jetbrains-ide, sonarlint

Unable to add Sonar Lint   and `SonarCube` Plugin in Android Studio

Failed to Download

Plugin `SonarLint` was not installed : Cannot download
http://plugins.jetbrains.com/pluginManager/?action=download&id=org.sonarlint.idea&build=buildid&uuid=someuuid:
Status:407

Below Error message was shown :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue has been resolved ,

Error 407 is comes when Proxy Authentication is required and its not validate because of not set proxy details or proxy credentials changed .

in my case proxy credentials was changed and not updated by me.